# git add --patch shows "^m" when I hit return

Tags: git, macos, encoding, terminal

Sometimes when I'm using `git add --patch`, my Return and arrow keys stop working - when I hit them I see weird symbols.

For example, here's what I see now if I run `git add --patch` and hit 'return', 'left', 'right', 'down', 'up' (with a space in between each key):

```
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? ^M ^[[D ^[[C ^[[B ^[[A
```

This is clearly some kind of encoding issue, but it's only happening in `git` commands that require user input such as patch - when I go back to normal terminal operation, things work fine again.

This happens to me at least once a day, and the only solution I've found is to close the terminal window and open a new one!

What's causing this and how do I prevent it?

Further details: I'm using `zsh` in `Terminal` on OS X 10.10.2. Within terminal Preferences, "text encoding" is set to UTF-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to check you console configuration with `stty -a`
If one of my flag is signed as `icrnl` I have no problem. If I change it to `-icrnl` the result is like yours.

To solve it just execute 
`stty icrnl`

You can even add it in your zsh profile.

You can also check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/441744/pressing-enter-produces-m-instead-of-a-newline

Comment: `stty icrnl` fixes the problem, but how do I prevent it from happening in the first place? What could be changing my `stty` configuration?

Comment: As I said you can add the command in the zsh profile to be sure to start with a clean terminal, but... If you want to try to "catch" the command or the program that change your stty configuration you could try to follow this guide: http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/debugging-mysterious-stty.html